# What does "quick sync-up" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang, abbreviations

My team leader asked me the following question. I got confused about what to reply.

Can anyone help me on what it exactly means?

> Do you have few mins for quick sync-up?

Comment: Do you have a few minutes to meet me and bring me up to date?  ("Sync-up" means to talk to each other and "synchronize" information.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Sync up*** or *synch up* — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sync+up)

> *verb* To coordinate something with something else so that they operate at the same rate and in correspondence with each other:

Here, your Team Lead would like to know if you have time to meet with him/her and discuss about a particular matter (or exchange information, i.e. sync up).

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of that before, it does make sense, but it sounds like something a Cylon would say. Do you have time to "catch up" is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In computer and network science, when 2 computers' files are synchronized, they both have the exact same files. Sync-up is similar to that.

Your team leader wanted you to report what you've done since last meeting. He would also tell you his ideas, so your information is synchronized!